# Online music application design question on php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I was thinking of using mvc pattern while designing this app. How can I use mvc here ? The model will be stored in mysql but what will be the controller and what will be the view here ?

Comment: Pick a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/) and read its documentation. You have at least one misconception about what MVC is (models aren't "stored in mysql") and there are probably more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: model won't be stored in MySQL database - the data will, and model != database [sometimes it is very related, but it is not equal overall]. Your controllers will probably handle such things like:

- login
- logout
- register
- select album
- select song

The view would be HTML page, but probably also some external app or embedded JS that people can place in their pages.

Comment: Tomasz will both view and controller be in php ?

Comment: Controller will obviously be in PHP - you've tagged question with it. ;] Using PHP in view gives you the opportunity to have some more advanced logic when generating it. You may also use some templating engine as OPT or Twig, but I prefer to use clean PHP.

Comment: Tomasz can you give me some tips on how to keep view and controller separate ?? in the sense if i have a.php say it has a table like displaying all songs of an artist the user enters so a.php post method should send the request to getSong.php (which is the controller) right ?

Comment: Put both controller and view in classes. Make controller class instantiate view one and call render() from it, passing all the data your view will need. In the render method require() PHP file with all the HTML code or insert it in the file and then display HTML contents with PHP generated data using that passed from controller. I hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

Go do the Zend Framework tutorial. It's free (as is the framework) and it will probably save you hours and hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is not just something you can use in PHP by default, you need a framework. MVC is an acronym for Model View Controller, which is a style of web application development that takes advantage of layering tasks and separating out your data, views, and backend processing. These frameworks for web development are use when creating websites.

There are a bunch out there, with a few popular ones being the Zend Framework, CakePHP, and Symfony.

Comment: Actually it's trivially easy to separate your PHP application into models, views and controllers with no framework. MVC is simply a way of organizing your files.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, the model is a class that represents data, in you case it will be a class that represent a tables in your mysql database **e.g. Song class for song table.**

Views are front end representation of data e.g. A list of top ten song for given week.

Controllers are programs that processes user request and gather data from different models, then redirect you request to specific view.

You can make your mvc framework from scretch if you want but I recommend you use an open source framework.

I use CodeIgniter framework for MVC projects in PHP. It is small and easy to use.